# Adding ":before" to an external style class

Tags: css

I am using two .html files A and B.

A.html has style element Ax as follows

```
<style
  .Ax {
     content: ''
     disaply: 
  }
</style>
```

B.html has style element By as follows:

```
<style
  .By {
     content: ''
     disaply: 
  }

 < want to add .Ax:before here>??
</style>
```

I want to add .Ax:before in B.html. Basically I want to have one UI element before .Ax UI but the data of that UI element can be filled only in B.html. So  I want to make sure that it gets loaded before .Ax UI

How do I add ":before" to a style class in A.html to B.html? I have already used preserve to make sure both style elements name remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `content:` only works with `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. So you would need to define it more like this:

```
<style>
    .Ax {}
    .Ax:before {
        content: '';
    }
</style>
```

You could link both A.html and B.html to the same css file using the `<link/>` element in the `<head>`. - In that file you could define both `:before` styles.

```
.Ax {}
.By {}
.Ax:before,
.By:before {
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If we make sure both are linked, is it possible to avoid creation of new file?

Comment: If you linked to the same .css file, yes you can have ONE file for all your styles.